# how to combine 2 sums into 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle10g, oracle-apex

i have 2 table Transaksi_Nasabah (id,nominal,kategori,id_nasabah) and Nasabah (id,name,alamat) 
I made sum in where kategoi = 'Setor'

```
select 'Setor' AS NAMA,sum(nominal) AS Nominal from transaksi_nasabah where kategori='Setor'
```

result :

```
NAMA    NOMINAL
Setor   760000
```

and i make too with kategori='Tarik'

```
select 'Tarik' AS NAMA,sum(nominal) AS Nominal from transaksi_nasabah where kategori='Tarik'
```

Result :

```
NAMA    NOMINAL
Tarik   130000
```

and I want to make it in 1 table with expectations :

Result :

```
NAMA    NOMINAL
Setor   760000
Tarik   130000
```

how do i make it?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT kategori AS NAMA, SUM(nominal) AS Nominal 
FROM transaksi_nasabah 
WHERE kategori IN ('Setor', 'Tarik')
GROUP BY kategori
```